# Can't see teradata data provider in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, teradata

I've just installed visual studio 2013 and tried to setup Entity framework to access an teradata database.

I click on new ADO.NET entity model, then Generate from database, but on the data connection screen when I click "New Connection" I don't get teradata appearing the list of datasources. I only get two SQL server options.

Do I need to install something extra to get this to work?

I have installed teradata latest version from there website.

Comment: It seems that you machine is missing teradata driver...by the way teradata only provide db for vm version ..on top of that you need to installed teradata tools and utilties ..TTU package also..which will allow your studio to have teradata driver while creating ODBC connection.

Comment: I have installed teradata latest version from there website...... I mean, I have added ODBC drivers and connectors along with the teradata VS tools and utilities

Comment: are you able to connect using sql assistant..download TTU package from here https://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-windows-installation-package

Comment: yes exactly that is what I have downloaded. Even if I try to make a new connection from the server explorer I easily get success but when ever i try to make an entity data model it does not show any option

Comment: ok..for .NET i do not much experience but have you installed this https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/net-data-provider-for-teradata